# substring exercise from The Haskell Road to logic

Tags: haskell

I've recently started to work my way through the book The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths and programming by Keets Doets & Jan van Eijck (very very nice book).

In one of the exercises the task was to define substring: My solutions works
and is much shorter than that of the authors, however i'm not delusional on who is the better Logician.

So, what am i missing:

```
prefix :: String -> String -> Bool
prefix [] y          = True
prefix x []          = False
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x == y) && (prefix xs ys)

substring :: String -> String -> Bool
substring x []     = False
substring x (y:ys) | prefix x (y:ys) = True
                   | otherwise = substring x ys 

-- Thought the answer provided was a bit overdone
substring' :: String -> String -> Bool 
substring' [] ys = True 
substring' (x:xs) [] = False
substring' (x:xs) (y:ys) = ((x==y) && (prefix xs ys)) || (substring' (x:xs) ys)
```

kind regards Auke

Comment: Your solution has a small error, `substring [] []` is wrong. When you factor in a fix it's not that much shorter than the other solution. They could have used `prefix (x:xs) (y:ys)` instead of `((x==y) && (prefix xs ys))` which would be a bit nicer.

Comment: Thank you Willem, great answer. It is really enjoyable brain exercise :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I want to try out [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck)  for myself in a larger project, this was a good exercise for me. QuickCheck is a library that can automatically test your function in a property on generated testcases. You can also create your own generator, but I did not do that here.

First of all, I installed QuickCheck with `cabal install QuickCheck`. I imported the module via `import Test.QuickCheck` and then I defined the property:

```
prop_substring xs ys = substring xs ys == substring' xs ys
```

This property, if given to QuickCheck, will generate the arguments `xs` and `ys` as `String`. It will check whether the property is `True`, which should happen in this case, as both `substring` functions should return the same result, of course.

To QuickCheck the function, I used `verboseCheck prop_substring`. This will check it against 100 generated testcases. The first result was:

```
Failed:
""
""
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 1 test):
""
""
```

So: no, these two functions are not the same. This is because in your function, `substring`, you do not test for the base case that it is a substring if the first argument is empty, so I added one line:

```
substring [] ys = True
```

Then, I tested it again. Here are the last two example generated test cases:

```
Passed:
"C8Q<r6\195@\v_\195\DC1\170"
"E\219\DLE"
Passed:
"$ I\SYN\232\164\EOT9\182Ldah\255\173\DC2-B\DC2\SUBuF|\235iQ\236l\vS129\237x?}\187\229C\SYNUVUc/3bO7mE\ESCHB7V\DEL\FSM\EM\202^\162!\GS\DC3\\\nja\201\ESC\ENQOi"
"&?\USx>{\147\DC4g\171\EM\240Ha%\"C\ETX \SI\FS=\DC2\214V%H"
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

But this was only with 100 tests, what about more? You can use another function and use other arguments. Let's try with 100.000 testcases:

```
*Substring> quickCheckWith stdArgs { maxSuccess = 100000 } prop_substring
+++ OK, passed 100000 tests.
```

So yes, it seems that both functions deliver the same results! There are although two downfalls: the first one is that it is unlikely that QuickCheck will generate two strings with a `substring` in it. As it generates random `String`, it is more likely that it will generate two completely different `String`. This can be solved by creating your own generators. The second downfall is that QuickCheck does not give you a formal proof.

The first one can be analysed with properties. If we change `prop_substring` to:

```
prop_substring xs ys = 
  collect (substring xs ys) $
  (substring xs ys == substring' xs ys)
```

Then we collect the results, so we can see what percentage the results are. For 100.000 this is:

```
*Substring> quickCheckWith stdArgs { maxSuccess = 100000 } prop_substring
+++ OK, passed 100000 tests:
94% False
 5% True
```

So, roughly 5000 return `True`. You can also generate `xs` and `ys` and give the `substring`-functions the arguments `xs` and `xs++ys` or `xs` and `ys++xs` to test for only `True` cases. Both options pass 100.000 tests, so we can almost assume that both functions give the same results.

More information about QuickCheck is in a bit [outdated manual](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual.html). You can, for example, tell QuickCheck that you want a certain amount of `True` testcases, instead of a total number of success test cases (success also happens when both `substring` functions result in `False`).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed info Renzeee, this is why i love this community!! I will def use this .